# Apache .conf to redirect all http subdomains to corresponding https subdomains via wildcard alias

Tags: https, redirect, apache2, wildcard-subdomain

I need to point each `http://sub.example.com` subdomain to its corresponding `https://sub.example.com`.

This is for use with WordPress multisite and my wildcard DNS records and wildcard Certbot cert. Everything works on `http`, now I need it all to be `https`.

I use/need this and it works with all http:

```
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

I need my Apache config, ***NOT via `.htaccess`***, to end up with something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

   <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerName example.com
            ServerAlias *.example.com

     #Other apache settings, incl SSL
   </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

   <VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerName example.com
           ServerAlias *.example.com*
           Redirect permanent / https://*.example.com/
     #Other apache settings
   </VirtualHost>
```

*(Please don't troll, don't down vote without explanation or a concise DUP that solves SSL with WordPress multisite via Apache .conf. I'm not interested in the 200+ upvoted encycopledia DUP on Rewrite, just what should go in my `.conf`.)*